# uGet cannot handle large file

Tags: uget

I used uget to download the following file:

http://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/aarddict/enwiki/enwiki20170202-slob/enwiki-20170202.slob

The download process reached 4392 MB (about 30 percent) without any problem, but after that every time I pause the downloading process, the file size is back to 4392 MB, so it's not making any progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug that has since been fixed, please update your uGet version.

Source: http://ugetdm.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=1541